# Java convert String to Object and then to JSON

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I use Java 8, Spring Boot etc.

I have the following problem:

1. I save JSON from request body to Mongodb as text: `{"MyValue1": "False"}`
2. Then I get the value from Mongo: `ControllerApi.findById(someParam)`
   As a result I get `DisplayObject` with a field:

private Object response (class generated by openapi); like: `"{MyValue1: False}"`

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"commandId", "response"})
public class DisplayObject{
    public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_COMMAND_ID = "commandId";
    private String commandId;
    public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_RESPONSE = "response";
    private Object response;
}
```

And response value is: `"{MyValue1: False}"`

3. Then I try to convert "response" object to my POJO:

   ```
   public class MyResult   {
    private Boolean MyValue1;
    private Boolean MyValue2;
    private Boolean MyValue3;
   ```

   }

But I get the error:

```
Encountered error converting from json
```

because ObjectMapper can't convert this String: `response.toString()` to `MyResult`.

The question is why
`ControllerApi.findById(someParam)`
returned object `DisplayObject` with a field Object response with value `"{MyValue1: False}"` instead of `"{"MyValue1": "False"}"`???

What should I do? Change the field response in DisplayObject to JsonNode?

Or maybe should I use String instead of Object for `response` field in my `DisplayObject`

**UPDATE**:

In Mongo I have `{"MyValue1": "False"}`

but after invoking endpoint with response body DisplayObject
as a result in field `DisplayObject.response` I get `{MyValue1=False}`

WHY???? What's going on??? I really have NO IDEA

Comment: Is DisplayObject a custom class or a MongoDB class or other? If so, link to it or edit post with custom class.

Comment: Please share you code and a stracktrace of the error.

Comment: @Jason DisplayObject class added - its my custom class

Comment: response json can have MyValue1 or only MyValue2 or both -> its not the problem because there are mapped only not null values to my POJO MyResult... The rest of the fields is just empty or null

Comment: @Matley are you sure `"{MyValue1: False}"` is this the response you are getting from this `ControllerApi.findById(someParam)`? and are you able to convert it back to `DisplayObject`

Comment: Yes because I get the message in the logs: "message":"Response command from agent: class OaDisplayCommand {\n    commandId: a4bfafb2-92fa-49e8-9fab-84a31aebcd51\n  response: {MyValue1=False}\n

Comment: So you say that fetching data from Mongo and saving in field of type Object is OK? So if yes, the question is why quotation marks disappeared after mapping to Object from Mongo...